# How can I query mysql from one node and then filter on spark?

Tags: mysql, apache-spark

I want to do something like this:

Firstly, generate a random number, and then query it in `mysql`. If it exists in `mysql database`, I will further search more information about it in `spark`.

However, if I `submit` the job to `spark cluster`, every node of the cluster will generate a different random number, and then query it in `mysql`, and than search in `spark`. Am I right?

I would want only one machine(node) generate a random number and query it in mysql, and then search it in `spark cluster` if it exists in `mysql`.

Also, the process above should be executed repeatedly.

How can I do it? Any help or hint would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Do your random-number generation and MySQL-queries in a loop **in the driver** of your Spark program, then for each  result generate a new Spark job from your follow-up query. For best performance do so asynchronously, then you can use Spark's built in scheduler (in this case FIFO is probably better suited) to keep cluster utilization high.

Comment: Thank you Rick. But if I just write the code in sequence in scala, say "generating the random number, querying in mysql, reading file from HDFS, and filter from the file", will it automatically run them in the driver and in the cluster seperately? As you said about "asynchronously", I think producer-consumer mode may be a good choice. However, I just want to keep my code simple now~

Comment: Any operation that doesn't RDD or DataSet API will run only on the driver. So something simple like 1 to 10.par.map(Random.nextInt) will run on the driver. Any DataSet/RDD operation will only generate a Job initially, and you can submit multiple jobs to Spark, while the first is still running. You only have to use the inherent parallelism of your code to be able to do so, and Scala parallel collections, or any other abstraction over multithreading. Your code will remain very simple. The reading from HDFS should be done using an initial DataSet operation - automatically parallelizing execution.